# Dotnetbar-populate only Single externally added column of supergrid from table

Tags: c#, sql, dotnetbar

I am using DotnetBar,
Have used Supergrid and populated its grid panel by data from particular table,
Now I have dynamically added a Column as shown below,

```
GridPanel panel = superGridControl.PrimaryGrid;

 string query = @"select ........";
        DataSet ds_classes = RunQuery(query); // RunQuery is method to
                                              // connect to the database and 
                                           // execute the query to return Dataset
        if (ds_classes.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            panel.DataSource = ds_classes.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
GridColumn gc = new GridColumn();
gc.HeaderText = "Attribute Type";
panel.Columns.Add(gc);
```

which is shown in below image

[image]

here ID and ATRIBUTES column get populated by different dataset, and I just want Attribute Type column should get populated by different dataset,

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use  event  GetCellValue in grid

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join in your query to join the two tables and then display that. You can omit the code that adds the column.